# why is my second listview empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I'm stumped. I have 2 relatively identical nested listviews, on a button Click event, the first listview is fine, the second one however is empty:

aspx:

```
...
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfCourseId" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Value="" />
...


<asp:listView ... ID="lvResponseNames">
...
   <InsertItemTemplate>
       <asp:ListView ... ID="lvQuestions" DataSourceId="sdsQuestions" onItemDataBound="lvQuestions_ItemDataBound">
           <ItemTemplate>
                 ...
           </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:ListView>
       <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsQuestions" ...
            SelectCommand="SELECT col1, col2, col3 from tbl where id=0">
       </asp:SqlDataSource>
       <asp:ListView ... ID="lvAdditionalQs" DataSourceId="sdsAdditionalQuestions" onItemDataBound="lvAdditionalQuestions_ItemDataBound">
          <ItemTemplate>
                 ...              
          </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:ListView>
       <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsAdditionalQuestions" ...
            SelectCommand="SELECT col1, col2, col3 from tbl where id=@CourseId">
            <SelectParameters>
               <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="hfCourseId" Name="CourseId" PropertyName="Value" />
            </SelectParameters>
       </asp:SqlDataSource>        
       <asp:Button ID="CustomInsertButton" runat="server" Text="Insert Attendee Responses >>" OnClick="CustomInsertButton_Click" />
   </InsertItemTemplate>     
<asp:listView ... ID="lvResponseNames">
```

aspx.cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ...
     if (int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["CourseId"], out iCourseId)
     hfCourseId.Value = iCourseId; 

}

...

protected void CustomInsertButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    //Default Questions
    ListView lvQs = (ListView)lvResponseNames.InsertItem.FindControl("lvQuestions") as ListView;
    Response.Write("Checking " + lvQs.Items.Count + " Defualt list view items. <br />");
    SqlDataSource dsDef = (SqlDataSource)lvResponseNames.InsertItem.FindControl("sdsQuestions") as SqlDataSource;
    DataView dvDef = (DataView)dsDef.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
    Response.Write("Checking " + dvDef.Count + " records found in datasource 'Default'. <br />");

    //Additional Quesetions
    ListView lvAQs = (ListView)lvResponseNames.InsertItem.FindControl("lvAdditionalQs") as ListView;
    Response.Write("Checking " + lvAQs.Items.Count + " Additional list view items. <br />");
    SqlDataSource dsAQs = (SqlDataSource)lvResponseNames.InsertItem.FindControl("sdsAdditionalQuestions") as SqlDataSource;
    DataView dvAQs = (DataView)dsAQs.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
    Response.Write("Checking " + dvAQs.Count + " records found in datasource 'Additional'. <br />");
    ...
}
```

Which outputs:

```
Checking 9 Defualt list view items. 
Checking 9 records found in datasource 'Default'. 
Checking 0 Additional list view items. 
Checking 6 records found in datasource 'Additional'.
```

The "0 Additional" should read 6, just like the Default one, but for the life of me, I can't figure out why it's not 'seeing' all the ItemTemplates.

Any ideas, or thoughts now how to debug?

**Update 4/1/14 9:45PM**: Added sqldatasource SelectCommands, because the issue appears to be connected to the ControlParameter on the second SqlDataSource.

When the select command is:

```
 SelectCommand="SELECT col1, col2, col3 from tbl where id=0"
```

it works fine.

But when it's:

```
 SelectCommand="SELECT col1, col2, col3 from tbl where id=@CourseId"
```

The items found is 0.  Somehow it's not finding the control ID, even though the DataSource is finding 9 items.

Comment: How are you passing the value to `@CourseId`? I would double check that you are passing that parameter correctly, because it's clearly not reading it.

Comment: I think you should be passing it in your `Select` statement, no? Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks @MilesWatson, that appears to be what was happening. I'm not sure portions of code to copy here, that aren't already shown, notice in the page_load the hfCourseId is being set, so I'm not sure why the nested listview didn't pick it up.  But I changed the code a bit, and used an asp:QueryStringParameter instead, and that did the trick.  Thanks!

Comment: No problem. You should mark your answer as correct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up re-factoring the code a little bit to use a

```
<asp:QueryStringParameter Name="CourseId" QueryStringField="CourseId" />
```

instead of:

```
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="hfCourseId" Name="CourseId" PropertyName="Value" />
```

Even though I was setting the hfCourseId in the code behind, for some reason it didn't appear to be set in the way I needed it.  Probably something to with the asp.net Page Life Cycle. But changing the code a bit, and using the CourseId as a QueryStringParameter seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at what you're getting from the database? Perhaps you are getting 6 records with nothing in them or something like that. Just a guess.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I did check that. I'm not sure why the datasource is getting 6 records, but the listview shows 0.  I checked the database, and the query using sql profiler, and the right query is being done, which is finding 6 records.  it's just a mystery the listview is empty.